# Получить системный цвет ОС

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import tkinter as ttk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = ttk.Tk()

fig = Figure(facecolor='#CCCCFF')
canv = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canv._tkcanvas.pack(
    side=ttk.BOTTOM, fill=ttk.BOTH, expand=ttk.YES)
root.mainloop()
```

Хочу в `Figure(facecolor='#CCCCFF')` вместо `#CCCCFF` передавать цвет, который по умолчанию использует ОС, чтобы приложение по цвету сочеталось с приложениями ОС. Как можно получить системный цвет?

Comment: а если facecolor вообще не передавать? просто fig = Figure()

Comment: что за системный цвет? системный цвет чего?

Comment: если facecolor вообще не передавать то будет темный серый цвет, который по умолчанию использует tkinter. А системный цвет, это который используется в рамке окошек windows